# Nav Menu hover states

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm hitting an issue with my header navigation. We want to make it so when you hover over an item in the nav menu the section is fully green. I have the submenu working perfectly but the main menu items are being difficult and not filling their section and fidgeting when hovered over. Also when you drill down into the sub menu it's highlighting the main nav at the top of the menu even though you're not hovering over it.

Below is the section I used to make the sub nav section function properly (style.css).

```
.nav-menu li.current_page_parent > a, .nav-menu li > a:hover {
color: #fff;
padding: 6.5px 10px;
background-color: #009444;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: -7px 0px 0px -10px;}
```

Any help would be great!

**Home page**
http://df50mobilewpe.wpengine.com

**Example clinic page**
http://df50mobilewpe.wpengine.com/clinics/premier-health-care-finder_aberdeen-south-dakota_brown-county-community-health-center-2/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: remove the padding from your "inner-wrapper" and add it to the list items. remove the hover background change from the <a>-tags and assign it to the <li>-tags. also remove all those negative-margins and paddings on <a> to prevent the menu-items from "jumping".

Comment: Blog item is highlighted because you need to remove "current_page_parent" from class "menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-254 menu-item-blog". A better way to manage your menu is to use a static version instead of php code to reduce requests and hence faster loading time.

Comment: Don't listen to @MrJackMcfreder, he doesn't know what he's talking about. Building a page (and it's menu) via PHP is an everyday practice and does not create additional requests. Concatenating and minifying files on the other hand will reduce requests and improve load times.

Comment: @hungerstar Sure buddy! You are speaking to a 10+ years Wordpress expert.

Comment: You obviously didn't learn a lot in a decade, :P. Perhaps you were referring to caching techniques instead of actual static files for a menu in WordPress.

Comment: @hungerstar is right. PHP if used correctly can save memory,time and bandwidth

Comment: This has bee very helpful! I updated it and it's almost there. It no longer jitters or highlights the wrong page. But the top nav still isn't fully being covered. What am I still missing?

Answer (score 0):

Because you want the entire list item to have the background, just add the background to the list item / the `li` element.

Change:

```
.nav-menu li.current_page_parent > a,
.nav-menu li > a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6.5px 10px;
    background-color:#009444;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:-7px 0px 0px -10px;
}
```

To:

```
.nav-menu li {
  padding: 6.5px 25px;
}

.nav-menu li.current_page_parent > a,
.nav-menu li > a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu li.current_page_parent,
.nav-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #009444;
}
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world would you change padding and margin after hover ?
Just set them before and background can be changed after hover

```
nav-menu li.current_page_parent>a, .nav-menu li>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #009444;
    display: block;
}

.nav-menu li a, .footer-nav-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6.5px 10px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: -7px 0 0 -10px;
}
```

This will remove the fidgeting.

Since you want the item to be fully green, you need to apply `background` green to the `li`

```
.nav-menu li:hover {
        background-color: #009444;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the margin from the ul tag

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

why? cause we gonna add this margin in other tag

remove these selectors, just keep the border-right: 0

```
.nav-menu li:first-child, .nav-menu li.first a, .footer-nav-menu li:first-child a, .footer-nav-menu li.first a {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-menu li:last-child, .nav-menu li.last a, .footer-nav-menu li:last-child a, .footer-nav-menu li.last a {
    padding-right: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}
.nav-menu li.current_page_parent > a, .nav-menu li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6.5px 10px;
    background-color: #009444;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -7px 0px 0px -10px;
}
```

add these selectors

```
.nav-menu > li{
  padding: 0 23px;
}
.nav-menu > li:hover{
  background-color: #009444;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-menu > li > a{
  color: inherit
}
```